# Is the closure of the sobolev space $H^1(\Omega)$ equal to $L^2(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

I am not mathematician (engineer) and would like to know whether the closure of the well-known sobolev space $H^1(\Omega)$ is equal to $L^2(\Omega)$.

My attempt: $H^1(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^2(\Omega)$ (because $C_0^\infty$ is contained in $H^1(\Omega)$) and $H^1(\Omega)\subset L^2(\Omega)$ therefore $L^2(\Omega)$ is the closure. I am not sure if this is the right way to prove the statement

Comment: Yes, your proof works.

Comment: You should make clear that it is the closure with respect to the $L^2$ norm.

Comment: And therefore $H^1(\Omega)$ is not closed subset of $L^2(\Omega)$ (w.r.t $L^2$-norm) since a closed set = its closure.